# How to repoen Java's Console without restarting application?

Tags: java, debugging, console, restart

I use the Java Console to debug / QA my company's products but sometimes I accidentally hit the "Close" button and in order to see the window again, I have to restart the entire application.

Is there an easier way to reopen the Java Console without having to restart the application?

Edit: I test the Java application on Windows, Linux, and OSX

Comment: What Operating System are you using?

Comment: Windows, Linux, OSX :)

Comment: This may be a duplicate of another question that was never answered: http://superuser.com/questions/351164/how-do-i-display-the-java-console

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how you would get this done in Windows , but you should look into `screen`.

To start your application:

```
bash$ screen
bash$ ./program
```

then if you accidentally close the window, all you have to do is:

```
bash$ screen -r
```

To detach from a screen you are looking at you need this key combination:

```
ctrl-a + d
```

^ This means press `ctrl` and `a` at the same time, then release keys and press `d`

the program should come to the forground so you can interact with it. I don't know if Max OSX comes with `screen`, but if it doesn't it can easily be installed using `brew install screen`.

Anyone who has more information on how you could do this in Windows, feel free to expand this post or post another answer.